# fireEvent.change() does not work - it has undefined value on input change

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, testing-libraryreact-native

I'm getting `undefined` for `event.target.value` on an input change event triggered by `fireEvent.change()` in the code bellow:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import React from "react";
import {
  fireEvent,
  render,
} from "@testing-library/react";

jest.mock('@material-ui/pickers', () => {
  const MockedMuiPickersUtilsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return <div data-testid="mocked-mui-pickers-utils-provider">{children}</div>;
  };

  const MockedDatePicker = ({ onChange, value }) => {
    const handleDateChange = (event) => {
      const selectedDate = event.target.value;
      console.log('Selected Date: ', selectedDate);
      onChange(selectedDate);
    };
    
    return (
      <input
        value={value}
        type="date"
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        data-testid='my-datepicker-test-id'
      />
    );
  };
  return { MuiPickersUtilsProvider: MockedMuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker: MockedDatePicker };
});

describe("Input date", () => {
  it('input value should be defined', async () => {
    const component = render(<MyComponent />);
    const inputDate = component.getByTestId('my-datepicker-test-id');
    const date = new Date('2023-07-18');

    fireEvent.change(inputDate, { target: { value: date } });

    expect(inputDate.value).toBe(date);
  });
});
```

Result:

```
FAIL

expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected: 2023-08-18T00:00:00.000Z
Received: ""
```

Why `fireEvent.change()` would not reflect the value properly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the value format, since the input is of type date the [thetesting-library/react doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireeventeventname) says that:

> The 'value' attribute must use ISO 8601 format when firing a change
> event on an input of type 'date'. Otherwise the element will not
> reflect the changed value.

```
// Invalid:
fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: '24/05/2020'}})

// Valid:
fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: '2020-05-24'}})
```

So the test should be written the following way in order to work:

```
it('input value should be defined', async () => {
    const component = render(<MyComponent />);
    const inputDate = component.getByTestId('my-datepicker-test-id');
    const date = '2023-07-18';

    fireEvent.change(inputDate, { target: { value: date } });

    expect(inputDate.value).toBe(date);
});
```

Comment: Notice that the value received in the `value={value}` input property must be in the right format equal. Otherwise the `inputDate.value` will be empty ("") in `expect(inputDate.value).toBe(date)`